# Removing items from a multi-select input element

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angularjs, multi-select

I'm looking to incorporate delete functionality in a multi-select element exactly how it is done here, on stackoverflow, when you post a question and then select multiple tags for  the question. Once an item is selected I want to add the close icon next to it so that a user can click the "close/remove" icon and remove the item from the selections one at a time.

I'm wondering if anybody can point out a tutorial or let me know the steps to incorporate the functionality I mentioned above. I currently have the following code, which is basically an input element and a list dropdown, which a user can click and select a row, which then puts the name property into the input, just like the tag functionality here.

I'm a little confused on how to go about adding that "close" icon and background once the selection has been made?

```
   <input  type="text" class="form-control no-select" name="inputField" placeholder="{{ctrl.placeholder}}" 
    ng-model="ctrl.ngModelValue" ng-click="ctrl.openDropdown($event)"/>

   <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th ng-repeat="heading in ctrl.gridColumnHeaders" class="text-center">{{heading}}</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="row in ctrl.filteredItems" ng-mousedown="ctrl.onSelectedLocal(row, $event)">
                <td ng-repeat="value in ctrl.sort(row) track by $index" class="text-center">
                    {{value}}
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Clicking the input toggles the dropdown open, a user can then click a row to select it, once that row is selected it sits as part of an array of selected items in the ng-model in the input, but I want to add the close icon to it? How can I do that?

Thanks

Example data being looped through in the table inside the ng-repeat:

```
  [
        { name: 'Jim', city: 'Minneapolis', state: 'MN', zip: 44332 },
        { name: 'Boe', city: 'Scottsdale', state: 'AZ', zip: 44332 },
        { name: 'Tom', city: 'S.F.', state: 'CA', zip: 11223 },
        { name: 'Joe', city: 'Dallas', state: 'TX', zip: 34543 },
        { name: 'Jon', city: 'L.A.', state: 'CA', zip: 56433 },
    ];
```

Answer (score 0):

adding something like

```
<button ng-class="hidden:ctrl.selectedItems.indexOf(value) !== -1"></button>
```

should do the trick

```
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th ng-repeat="heading in ctrl.gridColumnHeaders" class="text-center">{{heading}}</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="row in ctrl.filteredItems" ng-mousedown="ctrl.onSelectedLocal(row, $event)">
            <tr ng-repeat="value in ctrl.sort(row) track by $index" class="text-center">
                <td>{{value}}</td>
                <td><button ng-class="hidden:ctrl.selectedItems.indexOf(value) !== -1"></button</td>
            </tr>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

You could also set a property of selected on the item itself, that way you wouldn't have to do an indexOf Operation.

So it would be

```
<button ng-class="hidden:value.selected === false"></button>
```

Comment: Thanks Matt, I tried that and its currently showing on every element in the ng-repeat...I'd like to add the 'fa fa-close' icon to the name property of the selected row, inside the input, once it has been selected. But not before that. I added some example data to the bottom of my post above. I want to add the "fa fa-close" to the right of each "name" property selected so it would look something like this attached to ng-model inside the input: Jim x | Boe x | Tom x | Joe x | Jon x. They can click the x to remove the selection. Does the hidden button have to go inside the input not the table?

Comment: I'm still looking for potential answers here if anybody thinks they have a solution! Thanks